# When is the SQLite database created?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am learning SQLite database in android, as I know, we normally use the pattern below (see the code snippet), my understanding is that

1. When the `NoteDbHelpe` obj is instantiated, the constructor is
   called, it will check if the corresponding database is created.
2. If not, create the database and call the `onCreate` to create the tables.
3. If yes, see if we need to upgrade the database, if yes, call the `onUpgrade`.

My main concern is about when the database is created, I think it should be handled in the constructor, does my understanding correct?

```
    public class NoteDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "notes_db";

    public NoteDbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

     public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
         String createNoteTableSql = "CREATE TABLE ...";
         db.execSQL(createNoteTableSql);
     }

    @Override
     public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
         db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + NOTE_TABLE_NAME);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }
```

Comment: The onCreate method will be called after first access to the DB. Make a query to the DB and onCreate will be invoked.

Similar question already asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10147888/sqliteopenhelper-oncreate-is-not-called-the-db-does-not-exist/10148517#10148517

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just view [source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.java)

`onCreate` is called from `getDatabaseLocked` which is called from `getWritableDatabase` and `getReadableDatabase`.

Answer (score 3):

No, the database is *not* created when the helper is constructed. Instead, it is opened (and created if needed) when it is first used. The [documentations](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#getWritableDatabase%28%29) are very clear about this:

> ```
> public SQLiteDatabase getWritableDatabase ()
> ```
>
> Create and/or open a database that will be used for reading and
>   writing. The first time this is called, the database will be opened
>   and `onCreate(SQLiteDatabase)`, `onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase, int, int)`
>   and/or `onOpen(SQLiteDatabase)` will be called.

The reasoning for this is in the class overview:

> This class makes it easy for `ContentProvider` implementations to defer
>   opening and upgrading the database until first use, **to avoid blocking
>   application startup with long-running database upgrades.**